# Usage of Composer auto-loader (for loading external libraries) in Zend 1.12?

Tags: php, zend-framework, composer-php, autoload

Basically, I'd want to use Composer auto-loader (for loading third-party libraries), but I want to continue using built-in mechanism for auto-loading in Zend 1.12

I added the following piece of code:

```
<?php // File path: index.php 

// ...

$composerAutoloaderPaths = array(
    '../vendor/autoload.php',
    '../../common/vendor/autoload.php' // store common libraries used by multiple projects, currently that's working by adding the directory in set_include_path()
);

foreach($composerAutoloaderPaths as $composerAutoloaderPath)
{
    if(file_exists($composerAutoloaderPath))
    {
        require_once $composerAutoloaderPath;
    }
    else 
    {
        // handle the error gracefully
    }
}

// ...
```

Also, I'm using `Zend_Loader_Autoloader` like this:

```
<?php // File path: Bootstrap.php 

// ...

$autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();

$autoloader->registerNamespace('Plugin_');
$autoloader->registerNamespace('Helper_');
// etc.

// ...
```

Is there something to worry about using Composer and Zend autoloaders like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I often encounter this problem and I believe it's not an actual problem.

The best way IMO is to just include the composer autoloader in `public/index.php` as it's done in ZF2/3. This will not change a thing about the rest of the autoloading : https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/public/index.php#L21

Beware: if you used another entry point in your application (for cron scripts for instance), you'd need to add the same lines (basically in each entrypoint of your application).

Also, if you look at the rules in phpmd, one gives this message:

> A file should declare new symbols (classes, functions, constants, etc.) and cause no other side effects, or it should execute logic with side effects, but should not do both.

Therefore, declaring the include of the vendor autoloader in the bootstrap could be considered as a malpractice (at least seems to be a shared opinion between whoever wrote this rule and myself :)).

Answer (score 1):

You can autoload vendor in bootstrap.php like that:
`<?php // File path: Bootstrap.php 
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
    /**
     * Inits Vendor
     */
    protected function _initVendor()
    {
        require_once APPLICATION_PATH . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
       //  require_once APPLICATION_PATH . '/new/path/autoload.php';
    }
...
autoload whatever you want with Zend 1
...
}`

I have to advise you to use is_file() instead of file_exists() because file_exists returns true when directory exists, but not necessary when `.php` file exists

Answer (score 1):

I have to admire your resilience with ZF1, we all have been there 10 years ago. Zend Framework 1.x is full of require_once within its classes.
You can require_once another file anytime on Bootstrap.php file anytime